# PIX 515 Vlan cannot access the internet

Tags: vlan, cisco-pix

I have a vlan configured behind a PIX and the main network can get to the internet but the vlan devices cannot get to the internet. I have tried configuring a virtual vlan interface on the inside interface but that didn't help either. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to be more clear, did you define this VLAN on the PIX itself, or on a switch or router attached to the PIX?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your pix for authorize traffic , deal with ACLs , NAT and global commands !!!

Now i'am sick because i don't find the way for routing datas between the interfaces my pix 515